# ArangoDB get document by _id with cache per query

Tags: database, performance, arangodb, aql

Have document collections "items", and "dictionary1", "dictionary2"

```
collection "items" have 50000 records, like
{
label:"..."
dict1: "dictionary1/33333"
dict2: "dictionary2/44444"
....
}
```

When I join dictionaries with

```
FOR item IN items
LET dictname = FIRST(FOR d IN dictionary1 FILTER d._id == item.dict1 RETURN d.name)
RETURN { _id: item._id, name: item.name, dict: dictname }
```

Query execution time ~ 150ms its to much for this simple task. 
For experiment I am force dict for one _id

```
FOR item IN items
LET dictname = FIRST(FOR d IN dictionary1 FILTER d._id == "dictionary1/10000" RETURN d.name)
RETURN { _id: item._id, name: item.name, dict: dictname }
```

Query execution time ~ 130ms

Also I an tried DOCUMENT function

```
FOR item IN items
LET dictname = DOCUMENT("dictionary1", "dictionary1/10000")
RETURN { _id: item._id, name: item.name, dict: dictname.name }
```

Query execution time ~ 1500ms :((

And simple read from collection:

```
FOR item IN items
RETURN { _id: item._id, name: item.name }
```

Query execution time ~ 30ms

So result not cached when I get same document by _id 50000 times as join. 
Variant with duplicate content in one collection not useful for me.
Now I move logic to client side, select all dictionaries in memory and join after query, and have ~60ms, but I don't like this method, it wrong.

Any way to get result with joined dictionaries(80% same _id) with short time?

Comment: Did the answer fullfill your needs? If not, whats missing? If, can you mark it accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure that there is a matching item in `dictionary1` for each `items` that you loop over in the outer loop, the query can be simplified to a simpler equi-join like this:

```
FOR item IN items
  FOR d IN dictionary1 
    FILTER d._id == item.dict1
    RETURN { _id: item._id, name: item.name, dict: d.name }
```

This removes the need for the correlated subquery and the function call. However, its result will only be equivalent to the original subquery solution if there are matching `dictionary` entries for each `item`. If there is no `dictionary` entry for an `item`, the equi-join query will simply suppress it.

If it's unclear whether there'll be an entry in `dictionary1`, and you want `null`s to be returned for non-matches, the subquery solution can be simplified to (this removes the function call to `FIRST`):

```
FOR item IN items
  LET sub = (FOR d IN dictionary1 
    FILTER d._id == item.dict1
    RETURN d.name
  )
  RETURN { _id: item._id, name: item.name, dict: sub[0] }
```

Apart from that, joining on the `_key` attribute instead of joining on `_id` may provide minor speedups, as `_key` is shorter and less complex to produce than `_id`. But that will require storing the join values in `items` without the dictionary collection names prefixes.

The above suggestions shouldn't provide order-of-magnitude runtime improvements, but maybe they help.